# how do I go about removing all the language packs I don't need

Tags: package-management, language-support

I just noticed that in `/usr/share/help` I have the ubuntu help files in 70 different languages. I only speak 2, and I only really compute in one. I also noticed that it is full of broken symbolic links to /usr/share/help-langpack.

I want just want to get rid of all the languages I don't need. How can I do this without getting all `rm -r` happy? I'm preferably looking for a way to do this without installing any new packages, as my main goal is to get rid of excess stuff on my machine. I'd like to find a way to do this preferably with dpkg, or apt.

Comment: Those symlinks are part of a setup with the aim at **avoiding** to install help files in all languages on all machines. So yes, there are quite a few 'broken' symlinks, but that's better than the help files, right? My advice: Don't bother. The symlinks belong to various packages, and if you remove them, they will reappear next time respective package is updated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the following are from [Remove unwanted locales on Ubuntu / Debian](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/bittner-195120/remove-unwanted-locales-on-ubuntu-debian-3281/) in [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/) (some additional formatting applied):

**Which locales are installed on my machine?**

You can check which locales are generated and configured on your system using the `locale` command:

- `locale` ... list the current locale configuration
- `locale -a` ... lists all all locales that were generated on your system
- `locale -a -v` ... list all locales and show useful additional information (such as directory names that contain the locale information data files)

The last command makes you see that all generated locales are located in `/usr/lib/locale/`, you may remove any of them if unneeded. Each pack of `locale` information is a directory containing text files and other directories.

**Supported locales**

All locales that you want your system to support are listed in the text files in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`. These files have two columns, language tag and character map.

I want my system to know US-English only, so I have only one file there, called en, which contains just a single line:

```
en_US UTF-8
```

**Error messages**

If error messages are displayed when issuing the `locale` command, e.g:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

make sure the file `/etc/default/locale` exists and has proper content, such as:

```
LANG="en_US"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

**Get rid of unneeded locale data - Step by step**

Now we know all the necessary details to get started with cleaning up our system's locale information:

1. Edit the locale file(s) in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`, and remove all unneeded locales (one locale per line)
2. Create and edit `/etc/default/locale` (see above for an example)
3. Delete all generated locale data:

   ```
   rm -rfv /usr/lib/locale/*
   ```
4. Re-generate new locales:

   ```
   locale-gen
   ```

That's all! Reboot your machine to make your changes take effect. Then run one or more of the locale command examples from above to ensure yourself that the result is as expected.

```
~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
~# 
~# locale -a -v
locale: en_US.utf8      directory: /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | English locale for the USA
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | USA
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2000-06-24
  codeset | UTF-8
```

There is a package for Debian/Ubuntu that can take care of removing locales and locale related files (e.g. man pages): `localepurge`. You can install/run it issuing:

```
sudo apt-get install localepurge
```

once installed, you should run this:

```
dpkg --configure localepurge
```

to ensure your language settings are set correctly.

To run it manually once installed (although you shouldn't really need to as it should run after every `dpkg` run automagically), you can just do:

```
sudo localepurge
```

Read the man page before using it, though. If you can get your stuff done without it, it's probably safer to let go.

**References**

- [LocaleConf on official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf)
- [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale)
- [Locale on wikipeadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)
- [man localepurge](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/localepurge)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if I can't find a way to do this with what's already installed on my computer, I will definitely use this.

Comment: @knotech Why don't you just install it, run it and uninstall it. Not sure why your uptight about installing a package.

Comment: @knotech see official documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that localpurge addresses the OPs questions in any way.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The OP asked about language packs... But assuming that he is interested in removing redundant locales as well, why install localpurge? Why not just `locale-gen --purge`?

Answer (score 7):

As regards actually installed languages, go to *System Settings -> Language Support* and click the *Install / Remove Languages...* button. Then uncheck the languages you don't need.

As regards the symlinks in `/usr/share/help`, please see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is by using BleachBit. BleachBit is able to **remove files for unwanted languages in your system and applications**.

Install BleachBit from your Ubuntu Software or terminal (sudo apt install bleachbit) and open it as root (sudo bleachbit). Go to Preferences and under Languages check all the languages you want to keep. Now on the left panel, under System, check Localizations. If you want to know how much space these localization files are taking up in your system, click the Preview button. Use the Clean button to actually free up the space. Hope this helps.

In the screenshot, you can see BleachBit deleting localization files from gedit text editor.

[BleachBit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvlk7.jpg)

Comment: No answers so far address fonts. On my system, Synaptic reveals the existence of several that I will never use. Possibly Bleachbit addresses those; none of the other answers (so far) mentions fonts specifically. 

The OP expressed a preference for no additional software, but others have pointed out that one could install, run, and then remove a helpful package -- in this case, Bleachbit.