# How can I delete a pre-installed language in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, language-support

[image: screenshot of Language Support]

I have reinstalled my computer system with the Ubuntu 18.04 last night, and while I install the system I chose the system language is English but there is Chinese language package installed without my agreement now.
(What happened exactly?)

I try to remove this language in the **Install/Remove Languages...** button, but when I open the language setting, the system warns me there is some recommended package not installed and want to install it for me.
(I do not need it at all.)

So, is there any ways to remove this language showing in the screenshot?

P.s. I tried to upload the image many times and the upload page always says: `Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request`. So, I have to use Google Photos to share this screenshot.

Here is the outputs of commands `apt update && apt upgrade`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:3 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
Hit:6 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease     
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And the output of command `ls /usr/share/locale-langpack` is:

```
ls /usr/share/locale-langpack 
en  en_AU  en@boldquot  en_CA  en_GB  en@quot  en@shaw  en_US  zh  zh_CN
```

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/515330/how-do-i-go-about-removing-all-the-language-packs-i-dont-need

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Fine.Thx~

Comment: Just ignore the prompt to install language pack support, and go ahead and remove the Chinese language. (But first make sure that that language is not set as the "regional formats" setting.)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen After I followed the prompts on the page, I still couldn’t delete the Chinese language pack that appeared on the page.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson "Regional Formats" has been set as "English(United States)", I had been tried to remove this Chinese language but the "汉语(中国)" still appeared on the "Language Support" page now.

Comment: Then I suspect that the package system on your machine has been messed up in some way which is not directly related to languages. Can you please edit your question and let us know the output of the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok, I will post now.

Comment: Looks good; I was wrong about a general package system problem.

Comment: @Gunnar I don't see any Ubuntu repos in the output. Is that normal?

Comment: @wjandrea: Looks like Chinese mirrors to me.

Comment: I have another idea: What does the command `ls /usr/share/locale-langpack` output?

Comment: @wjandrea I am using the ubuntu mirror repos server now because of it faster than ubuntu official repos in the area where I living.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have changed the question and post the output in the question now.

Comment: Then run the command `sudo rmdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/zh` (to remove that folder, which is redundant and confuses the system).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Just remove the `zh` folder?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggest. (It's a harmless action.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok, I finished the operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81296/discussion-between-hatsune-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Mr.Hjalmarsson's help.

Follow this Steps:

First, make sure that language which you want to make it disappear in this page is not set as the "regional formats" setting.

Then check the folder which in `/usr/share/locale-langpack` and using command `ls` like this:

```
ls /usr/share/locale-lanpack/zh
en  en_AU  en@boldquot  en_CA  en_GB  en@quot  en@shaw  en_US  zh  zh_CN
```

We can see there has a language folder which you want to remove like `zh`, this `zh` folder was created by the installer since you (apparently) selected a Chinese time zone location, so we removed it now.

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/zh
```

At last, we use the command `gnome-language-selector` to remove the Chinese language packages again and re-open the `gnome-language-selector`, the "汉语(中国)" will never appear.

If you can't see the "汉语(中国)", we should do some clean work after remove, so, just remove all of the folders which have the characters `zh` in the folders name.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the `zh` folder was created by the installer since you (apparently) selected a Chinese time zone location. Personally I consider it to be a bug in the installer, but I won't get further into the details in this comment.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok, I will add your suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your languages pack supports with:

```
sudo apt search language-pack
```

if you want remove the Chinese language, try

```
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-zh-hans-base language-pack-zh-hant language-pack-zh-hant-base
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first command return this: `zsh: no matched found: language-pack*`, and I delete the character "*", it works.

Comment: @Hatsune Can you please edit your question and let us know the output

Comment: And the second command I have tried but while I open the "Language Support" there still warn you to install the recommended package. And the "汉语(中国)" was not disappearing.

Comment: The whole output of "apt search"?

Comment: @Hatsune i think close your gnome-language-selector first,  and try again with sudo apt-get remove check-language-support 1 zh. (zh is Chinese language code).

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: That latter command would be an attempt to remove non-installed packages. ;)